# Ways to attached an ICommand to a control in XAML

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, xaml, icommand, command-pattern

I'm very new to XAML.  To utilize MVC architecture and the Command Pattern while taking advantage of XAML, I have started binding static ICommands to Buttons.  I'm working on a fairly large project with over a hundred buttons.  My questions are: are there different approaches for binding commands to buttons to avoid static objects.  With regards to C#, WPF, and XAML, are statics commonly used?  I'm sure someone has already worked on a project using MVC, Command Pattern, and XAML, what was your approach?

I should have probably edited this sooner, but while working on the project, I've realized how much I didn't know about c#, WPF, and XAML when I asked this question.  Apparently, in WPF, instance properties make it convenient binding methods and data members to controls.

As far as MVC / MVVM are concerned, I guess I was hesitant to expose my model to VM before I even know what it is.

Comment: I understand that MVVM and XAML is most commonly used in WPF.  However, I have a model, a controller, a view, and a bunch of command classes which implements ICommand.  I'm taking advantage of XAML to create the buttons to which I bind static objects of my custom command classes.  I am more concern about the downside of having hundreds of static objects (my custom commands) bound to controls created in XAML.  Also, I'm wondering if anyone else is using XAML and MVC instead of XAML and MVVC.  I'm trying to take advantage of XAML without relying too much on MVVC that WPF employs by default.

Comment: I really appreciate your responses.  Thank you!  I have my architecture set up, and my program is working perfectly (so it seems).  I'm not having problems with WPF and XAML per se.  However, since this is my first WPF/XAML project, I'm more concern about how I'm putting it to use.  Simply put, I'm using XAML because of the simple and rich UI capability it provides.  There is probably no good reason to worry about over a hundred static objects, but somehow it bothers me.

Comment: @Big Daddy "WPF doesn't use MVVM or by default"
Isn't it true that on design mode, once you clicked on a button and it created the code behind, you are using MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the MVVM pattern as it applies to WPF.  That is Model View ViewModel

1. Model = used to construct the form model for the data being manipulated
2. View = Presentation (usually a main form and many user control forms)
3. ViewModel = code container for presenter (classes that contain the code)

Generally your binding take the place of ICommand methods that implement a RelayCommand from a base.  There is a lot to learn before implementing the MVVM model, I would suggest reading Josh Smith's article and downloading his example to get started on learning it:

There are special rules and principles to learn and this example will go through a lot of it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

I would also think it would be wise to learn how WPF performs bindings a little bit.  There are many special setups you can do with bindings to help with performing operations at different events and other places.  I do not even know all the bindings by heart but I know the more you learn them the more time you save in the end in your XAML coding as you can reuse, event trigger, inherit and do many things with bindings to make your applications more powerful than static creation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: "I would also think it would be wise to learn how WPF performs bindings a little bit."  I agree, and I actually ran into those links you've provided googling for "msdn wpf command bindings".  Most of the examples I've seen, however, use static objects or static variables.  I may have missed some things, but I would appreciate it if you could provide me a link to an example of binding without using a static object or variable.

Comment: When you do the binding in MVVM it usually happens like this with an example for a simple label: <Label id="labelTest" Content="{Binding Path=(property in viewmodel)}" />  This property is set in a non static class and can be updated one direction, one direction to source, or two way, along with many other options.  This way if I have a parent form and then want to inherit a value in a constructor I can, but I can change it and my View and ViewModel are seperated.  The binding example second link goes over this.  The important thing to know about binding is it can and often is event driven.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think, data binding and command binding works a little differently.  I did a little more reading on command binding and found that even the default commands provided by WPF are static RoutedCommand objects.  So, I think I'm headed in the right direction, but it would still be nice to hear from someone who has created a few custom commands which are bound to controls (specifically buttons) using XAML.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: You do ICommand binding with a similar process.  You merely tell the execution method to use an ICommand return.  It is similar to <Button Command={Binding Path=(MethodNameCommand)}".  The method is in your view model and generally calls the 'RelayCommand' to invoke another method.  This is generally given the name 'ButtonDoCommand' while it calls a command 'ButtonDo' or similar via relay.  It is all in the first example that has a complete code solution with it.

Comment: Which first example exactly are you talking about?  From the first link or second link?